# Proof of a dilogarithm identity

Tags: calculus, special-functions, closed-form, polylogarithm

Through some experimentation, I've found:

> $$\text{Li}_{2}(\sqrt{2}-1) \ + \text{Li}_{2}(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\  =\frac{\pi^2}{8} - \frac{\ln^2(1 + \sqrt{2})}{2} - \frac{\ln^2{2}}{8}  $$

I'm sure a simple proof is evading me, but I have not been able to prove this so far.
I've been able to reduce it to proving the following integral equality:
$$\frac{\ln^2{\sqrt{2}+1}}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{16}=\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1 \frac{\ln{t}}{1-t^2}$$
Which, again, agrees numerically but seems to be as hard as proving the original problem. How can I prove this dilogarithm identity?

Comment: I'd say show/use the [duplication formula $Li_2(z)+Li_2(-z) = \frac{Li_2(z^2)}{2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Properties) and the [Abel identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the standard notation $\operatorname{Li}_2$ for the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) and $\zeta$ for the [Riemann zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html). For $|z|<1$, [we have](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/02/0003/)
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(2z-z^2\right) = -\ln^2\left(2-z\right)+\zeta(2)-2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2-z}\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_2(z).
$$
This result can be obtained from [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm) by using appropriate transformations and substitutions. For further details see [Lewin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444005501), pp. 7$-$11.

Let $z:=1-\sqrt2$ and divide both side by $2$. We have
$$
\tfrac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-1) = -\tfrac12 \ln^2\left(1+\sqrt2\right)+\tfrac12\zeta(2) - \color{red}{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\sqrt2 - 1\right)} + \operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\sqrt2\right).\tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$

From the [duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Polylogarithm) and the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions) of the dilogarithm function, [we have](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/01/0001/)
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2(-1) = -\tfrac12 \operatorname{Li}_2(1) = -\tfrac12 \zeta(2).\tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$

Now if we express $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\sqrt2\right)$ from $\left(\spadesuit\right)$ and substitute $\left(\clubsuit\right)$, we arrive at
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\sqrt2\right) =  \color{red}{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\sqrt2 - 1\right)} + \color{blue}{\tfrac12 \ln^2\left(1+\sqrt2\right)-\tfrac34\zeta(2)}.\tag{$\heartsuit$}
$$
[Landen's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm) states that for $z \notin \left(-\infty,0\right]$, [we have](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/01/0009/)
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-z\right) + \operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)=-\tfrac12\ln^2(z).
$$

Let us substitute $z:=\sqrt2$ into Landen's identity. We arrive at
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\sqrt2\right) + \color{green}{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)}=\color{blue}{-\tfrac18\ln^2(2)}.\tag{$\diamondsuit$}
$$
Now if we combine $\left(\heartsuit\right)$ and $\left(\diamondsuit\right)$ and use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers) that $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$, we arrive at
$$
\color{red}{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\sqrt2 - 1\right)} + \color{green}{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)} = \color{blue}{\frac{\pi^2}{8} -\frac18\ln^2(2) - \frac12\ln^2\left(1+\sqrt2\right)}.
$$

---

From this argument we can derive a general identity. For $|1-z|<1$ and $z \notin (-\infty,0]$, we have

> $$
> \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right) = \tfrac12\left(\zeta(2)-\ln^2(z)-\ln^2(z+1)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-z^2\right)\right).
> $$

For $z:=\sqrt2$, we arrive at your particular problem. We give another example. For $z:=1/\sqrt{2}$, we have
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(2-\sqrt2\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{24} - \frac38\ln^2(2)+\ln(2)\ln\left(\sqrt{2}+2\right)-\frac12\ln^2\left(\sqrt{2}+2\right).
$$
At this example we used the [special value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function#Special_values) $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac12\ln^2(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Landen's identity

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=-\frac12\ln^2(1-x)$$

set $x=\sqrt{2}-1$ we get

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(\sqrt{2}-1)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}-2}\right)=-\frac12\ln^2(2-\sqrt{2})\tag{1}$$

we have $$\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}-2}*\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{\sqrt{2}+2}}\right)=\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

and by using $\ \operatorname{Li}_2(-x)=\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$ and setting $x=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ we get

$$\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac1{2}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

now lets use the refection formula for the last term on the right

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)&=\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac1{2}\right)-\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ln\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac1{2}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac12\ln2\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)+\frac14\ln^22+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}

Plugging $(2)$ in $(1)$, we get

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Li}_2(\sqrt{2}-1)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)&=-\frac12\ln^2(2-\sqrt{2})+\frac12\ln2\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)-\frac14\ln^22-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
&=-\frac{\ln^2(2-\sqrt{2})-\ln2\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2}-\frac14\ln^22-\frac12\left(\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac12\ln^22\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
&=-\frac{\ln^2(2-\sqrt{2})-\ln2\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\tag{3}
\end{align}

To simplify more, we write

$$\ln^2(2-\sqrt{2})=\ln^2\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\ln^2(1+\sqrt{2})-\ln2\ln(1+\sqrt{2})+\frac14\ln^22$$

and $$\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)=-\ln(\frac1{\sqrt{2}-1})=-\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)$$

therefore

$$\ln^2(2-\sqrt{2})-\ln2\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)=\ln^2(1+\sqrt{2})+\frac14\ln^22$$

Finally, plugging this result in $(3)$ we get

> $$\text{Li}_{2}(\sqrt{2}-1) \ + \text{Li}_{2}(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\  = - \frac{\ln^2(1 + \sqrt{2})}{2} - \frac{\ln^2{2}}{8}+\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

This identity was shown to be true in Theorem 4 of my paper published in 2012, see link to Elsevier site below.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357711000425

Fabio M. S. Lima